# How to use Tcp Variants Comparison in NS3?

Tags: tcp, ns-3

I need to compare different type of TCP using ns-3 for a class project. I am new with ns-3. I don't want to implement a new code. Briefly, I have 2 questions:

1. Which example of ns-3 is the best for my purpose? **Tcp-Variants-Comparison.cc**?
2. How can I see the output. I ran the code, but there was no output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run your example using `.waf`. Navigate to your ns-3 directory (the place where `.waf` executable is located) and run:

```
./waf --run tcp-variants-comparison
```

This will compile (if needed) and run the example with default arguments. You can change arguments using `--command-template="%s <args>"`. If you look inside the **tcp-variants-comparison.cc** you can see all available arguments, e.g.:

```
...
cmd.AddValue ("delay", "Access link delay", access_delay);
cmd.AddValue ("tracing", "Flag to enable/disable tracing", tracing);
cmd.AddValue ("tr_name", "Name of output trace file", tr_file_name);
cmd.AddValue ("cwnd_tr_name", "Name of output trace file", cwnd_tr_file_name);
...
```

So here is an example how you can store congestion window of default *TcpWestwood* protocol to **cwndTrace** file:

```
./waf --run tcp-variants-comparison --command-template="%s --tracing=1 --cwnd_tr_name=cwndTrace"
```

You can then use any tool you like to display the data. Here is how to plot it with `gnuplot`:

```
$ gnuplot
gnuplot> set terminal png size 640,480
gnuplot> set output "cwnd.png"
gnuplot> plot "cwndTrace" using 1:2 title 'Congestion Window' with linespoints
gnuplot> exit
```

You should also take a look at [this NS-3 tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/). This gives you a pretty good introduction to NS-3, so read it carefully.

[image: cwnd]

So to answer your question completely, you can use this example for comparison of:

```
cmd.AddValue ("transport_prot", "Transport protocol to use: TcpTahoe, TcpReno, TcpNewReno, TcpWestwood, TcpWestwoodPlus ", transport_prot);
```

So run this example with different `transport_prot` arguments and compare your traces.

Comment: Unfortunately in my ns3 there is no `cwnd_tr_name`. How can I get the output file for `tcp-variants-comparison` ?

Comment: @codddeer123 you are right they [removed](http://code.nsnam.org/ns-3-dev/diff/a4c1c237df2c/examples/tcp/tcp-variants-comparison.cc) this option.  However if you look into the code you will find the answer :)

`Simulator::Schedule (Seconds (0.00001), &TraceCwnd, prefix_file_name + "-cwnd.data");`

Comment: Hi @DimitriPodborski, thanks for your answer, but I got one problem, I can't either test TcpTahoe or TcpReno, so I'm wondering which version of ns3 were you using?

Comment: Hi @I.Lin, I don't remember. But you can search the [change logs](https://gitlab.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev/-/blob/master/CHANGES.html). I see that **Classes TcpRfc793, TcpTahoe, and TcpReno were removed** in Changes from ns-3.24 to ns-3.25

Comment: @DimitriPodborski thx, I found TcpTahoe in 3.24 version.