# showing results of tcp-variants-comparison.cc under ns3 3.28

Tags: ns-3

I am looking for a way to show the results of the file "tcp-variants-comparison.cc" under ns3 (3.28) used with Ubuntu 18.04.

I found here an old topic from 2013, but it seems not to work correctly in my current environment.

P.S: I am a newbie in ns3, so i will appreciate any help.

regards
cedkhader

Comment: Please provide a link to the old topic from 2013, could you also provide some of your attempts to allow us to help you find the issue.

Comment: question belong to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: dears ,thanks for the reply. the link for the old post of the same subject (tcp-variants-comparison.cc) is :                                                         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963678/how-to-use-tcp-variants-comparison-in-ns3 ,          i wish to know how to produce the .dat file for different parameters and protocols. Later i can produce the png pictures using the gnuplot tool under Ubuntu. Thanks in advance . cedkhader

Comment: i can run the (tcp-variants-comparison.cc) using ./waf , and it is correctly built without errors, but i cannot produce any .dat files to see the graph of the comparison of the different protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Running `./waf --run "tcp-variants-comparison --tracing=1"` yields the following files:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1  112271415 Aug  5 15:52 TcpVariantsComparison-ascii
-rw-rw-r--  1     401623 Aug  5 15:52 TcpVariantsComparison-cwnd.data
-rw-rw-r--  1    1216177 Aug  5 15:52 TcpVariantsComparison-inflight.data
-rw-rw-r--  1     947619 Aug  5 15:52 TcpVariantsComparison-next-rx.data
-rw-rw-r--  1     955550 Aug  5 15:52 TcpVariantsComparison-next-tx.data
-rw-rw-r--  1         38 Aug  5 15:51 TcpVariantsComparison-rto.data
-rw-rw-r--  1     482134 Aug  5 15:52 TcpVariantsComparison-rtt.data
-rw-rw-r--  1     346427 Aug  5 15:52 TcpVariantsComparison-ssth.data
```

You can use other command line arguments to generate the desired output, see list below.

```
Program Arguments:
    --transport_prot:    Transport protocol to use: TcpNewReno, TcpHybla, TcpHighSpeed, TcpHtcp, TcpVegas, TcpScalable, TcpVeno, TcpBic, TcpYeah, TcpIllinois, TcpWestwood, TcpWestwoodPlus, TcpLedbat  [TcpWestwood]
    --error_p:           Packet error rate [0]
    --bandwidth:         Bottleneck bandwidth [2Mbps]
    --delay:             Bottleneck delay [0.01ms]
    --access_bandwidth:  Access link bandwidth [10Mbps]
    --access_delay:      Access link delay [45ms]
    --tracing:           Flag to enable/disable tracing [true]
    --prefix_name:       Prefix of output trace file [TcpVariantsComparison]
    --data:              Number of Megabytes of data to transmit [0]
    --mtu:               Size of IP packets to send in bytes [400]
    --num_flows:         Number of flows [1]
    --duration:          Time to allow flows to run in seconds [100]
    --run:               Run index (for setting repeatable seeds) [0]
    --flow_monitor:      Enable flow monitor [false]
    --pcap_tracing:      Enable or disable PCAP tracing [false]
    --queue_disc_type:   Queue disc type for gateway (e.g. ns3::CoDelQueueDisc) [ns3::PfifoFastQueueDisc]
    --sack:              Enable or disable SACK option [true]
```

Answer (score 0):

in ns3.36.1 I used this command

```
./ns3 run examples/tcp/tcp-variants-comparison.cc -- --tracing=1
```

and output look like this

```
TcpVariantsComparison-ascii 
TcpVariantsComparison-cwnd.data 
TcpVariantsComparison-inflight.data 
TcpVariantsComparison-next-rx.data 
TcpVariantsComparison-next-tx.data 
TcpVariantsComparison-rto.data 
TcpVariantsComparison-rtt.data 
TcpVariantsComparison-ssth.data
```